# Eclipse compile project, but actually not

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I reinstall OS, pack my workspace on flash drive, with hopping, of just needing to copy/paste projects in workspace of ECLIPSE (luna) exactly i used on prior installation.

I included it all, no where **RED**. All seem ok, but.

I tried to change some behaivor on my program, and eclipse compile program regular, but on phone is the same program i stoped working on, prior reinstallation.

( *also tried to delete app, and install again )

Next what i done, to make me 100% sure that is eclipse issue, i add some obiviously exception, like not setting `setContentView`, and so on...

But it compile, and give me correct .apk.

What i tried:

Tried to change workspace, and copy/paste just src, res, and manifest file.

Also checked manifest file in bin, and it's exactly same as in root folder for project.

What to do? Is this some zombie

**EDIT** : Windows 8.1

Comment: What of the context etc? You mention none of it. You "reinstall OS": what OS is that? Etc etc

Comment: You are talking to complete strangers now that never seen your project.  Unless you provide relevant details how do you expect us to understand your particular situation?

Comment: Delete the .apk file that you think is being generated by Eclipse, then recompile and see if a new .apk is generated. Then see if it makes a difference when you load the .apk.

Comment: Sry for not mention os. I don't know what kind of information need to post about project, because this is odd question for me... Tried also with android studio same thing....

Answer (score 0):

I think copy/paste does not work. You need to import your projects into eclipse. Yu can do that by going to File>Import>Existing projects into workspace> and browse to your flash drive

Comment: didn't help. I install android studio, and same thing happend

Answer (score 0):

**so, this happend**
In transaction, somehow eclipse made new package

```
main_activities
```

And i was to fast to take look at that. My main activities what try to edit was in package with name

```
activities
```

I dont know why eclipse did that... 
I accidently take look at manifest file and found this issue...